# mediapipePose for single landmark not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mediapipe, pose

I want to place an selected image on left and right ear using media pose in react Js .But single landmark is not showing .I don't know what's the problem in my code .

```
draw Landmarks(canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks, mediapipePose.POSE_LANDMARKS_LEFT.LEFT_EYE);
```

I have tried too many times but not got the expected result.I need help from you guys .Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not roll back edits which objectively improve your post, such as adding code formatting in this case. You can refer to the [help centre's article on formatting](/help/formatting) if you'd like help on how to format your posts.

Comment: [draw the mask](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-segmentation#example-usage) to see what is going on

Comment: @Mechanic mask is not the solution for my problem ..i just want a single point like left eye point Landmark on it